# Best practive for socket client within EJB or CDI bean

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, ejb

my application must open a tcp socket connection to a server and listen to periodically incoming messages.

What are the best practices to implement this in a JEE 7 application?

Right now I have something like this:

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
public class MessageChecker {

   @Asynchronous
   public void startChecking() {

     // set up things
     Socket client = new Socket(...);
     [...]


     // start a loop to retrieve the incoming messages
     while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){

        LOG.debug("Message from socket server: " + line);

    }

   }
}
```

The MessageChecker.startChecking() function is called from a @Startup bean with a @PostConstruct method.

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
@Startup
public class Starter() {

   @Inject
   private MessageChecker checker;


   @PostConstruct
   public void startup() {
     checker.startChecking();
   }

}
```

Do you think this is the correct approach?
Actually it is not working well. The application server (JBoss 8 Wildfly) hangs and does not react to shutdown or re-deployment commands any more. I have the feeling that the it gets stuck in the while(...) loop.

Cheers
Frank

Comment: In short: you don't. If you cannot make your client talk a proper protocol (SOAP or JMS), implement your socket listener as servlet and make it call out to your EJB layer.

Comment: Could you illustrate that a little bit more? What I actually want to do is to fire a CDI event on each incoming socket message which then is processed by another EJB or CDI bean.

Answer (score 6):

Frank, it is bad practice to do any I/O operations while you're in an EJB context. The reason behind this is simple. When working in a cluster:

1. They will inherently block each other while waiting on I/O connection timeouts and all other I/O related waiting timeouts. That is if the connection does not block for an unspecified amount of time, in which case you will have to create another Thread which scans for dead connections.
2. Only one of the EJBs will be able to connect and send/recieve information , the others will just wait in line. This way your system will not scale. No matter how many how many EJBs you have in your cluster, only one will actually do its work.
3. Apparently you already ran into problems by doing that :) . Jboss 8 seems not to be able to properly create and destroy the bean.

Now, I know your bean is a `@Singleton` so your architecture does not rely on transactionality,  clustering and distribution of reading from that socket. So you might be ok with that.

However :D , you are asking for a java EE compliant way of solving this. Here is what should be done:

- Redesign your solution to go with JMS. It 'smells' like you are trying to provide an async `messaging` functionality (Send a message & wait for reply). You might be using a synchronous protocol to do async messaging. Just give it a thought.
- Create a JCA compliant adapter which will be injected in your EJB as a @Resource

  - You will have a connection pool configurable at AS level ( so you can have different values for different environments
  - You will have transactionality and rollback. Of course the rollback behavior will have to be coded by you
  - You can inject it via a @Resource annotation

There are some adapters out there, some might fit like a glove, some might be a bit overdesigned.

[Oracle JCA Adapter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10231/adptr_sock.htm#autoId0)

Comment: Great answer, thank you! However I have no control over the "server" and it is not my fault that it is a socket server ;-)